# What are the meanings of the different stones for different sons of Yisrael?

Tags: tetzaveh, kohen-gadol

[Shemot 28:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9889#showrashi=true&v=17)-21 describes the stones that are placed in the breastpiece (*choshen*) worn by the *kohein gadol*.  There are twelve different stones, each inscribed with the name of one of the sons of Yisrael.  Rashi indicates that they go in order, so the first stone listed is for Rueven, the second for Shimon, and so on.  This list is repeated in [Shemot 39:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9900#showrashi=true&v=10)-14.

What is the connection between each stone and its assigned name?  What makes אֹדֶם fitting for Rueven, פִּטְדָה for Shimon, and so on for the rest?  An answer to [this broader question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68098/472) says that Rabbenu Behaye describes the meanings of each of the stones, but the answer doesn't include most of them and I can't read the linked Hebrew source (and the question is broader, so I don't know if it's reasonable to expect an answer to do so).  I don't know if there are those who disagree with Rabbenu Behaye.

Assuming the assignments are in fact meaningful as that answer says, what are the meanings for all twelve stone/son pairings?

We were studying this recently and didn't find anything in any of the *chumashim* we had available (Stone, *Eitz Chayim*, Hertz, and Soncino at least).  These stones are also translated into English differently by different translations, we noticed.  I forget which, but one stone was translated as "onyx" in one *chumash* and "lapus lazuli" in another.  Those aren't even close, so perhaps we don't know what the stones are and thus can't understand any special meanings?

Comment: Precisely translating species names is notoriously difficult and this isn't an exception.

Comment: dupe i think http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68098/759

Comment: Argh, didn't find that one.  That one's more general; is it valid to ask a more-detailed question in case the generality of the other is impeding answers?  (I don't care about order of layout.)  I see the link in the answer there to Rabbenu Behaye, which I can't read, and it sounds like my question would be answered by what's on the other side of that link.  [Continued in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34638983#34638983).